# FTL replace multiple consecutive hyphens with one

Tags: java, freemarker

I have a string which looks like this:

`something-------another--thing`
I want to replace the multiple dashes with a single one from FTL.

So the expected output would be:

`something-another-thing`

The **?replace** will work if we know the exact number of hyphens, but I'm not sure about how many hyphens will come here in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Use `?replace('-+', '-', 'r')`. The `'r'` means that it uses regular expressions, and `-+` means one or more `-` characters in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
[#assign str = "a-b--c---d----e-----f"]

[#function reduceHyphens text]
    [#list 1..text?length as i]
        [#if text?contains("--")]
            [#local text = text?replace("--","-")]
        [#else]
            [#break]
        [/#if]
    [/#list]
    [#return text]
[/#function]

${reduceHyphens(str)}
```

output: a-b-c-d-e-f